# Using radio buttons in ASP - assigning checked

Tags: session, asp-classic

I have a snippit of code to check a session variable if my radio button value is Male or Female. Is there a cleaner way of doing this?

```
<input name="EmployeeSex" id="Female" type="radio" value="Female"  
    <% if Session("EmployeeSex") = "Female" then
            Response.Write("checked")   
       end if  
    %>
> Female
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<% if Session("EmployeeSex") = "Female" %>checked<% end if %>

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I was hoping there would be a better way then put a condition within my input tag. Maybe assigning the radio button as an object and assign the check attribute?

Comment: That's pretty much the way of writing such things in classic asp. I don't think there is a way of having an object defined and in any case the benefits of doing so would be surpassed by the hassle of working with such object in classic ASP.

Answer (score 0):

This is propably the nicest way, save for writing a WSC component that mimics ASP.NET MVC's "HTML" helper object:

```
<%
Dim cbCheck
if Session("EmployeeSex") = "Female" Then cbCheck="checked"
%>

<input name="EmployeeSex" id="Female" type="radio" value="Female" <%=cbCheck%>>
```

Erik